# cloud formation template using If condition provision two GSI NonKeyAttributes in dynamodb provision

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I want to provision dynamodb GSI Non keyattributes with two values based on parameter type using if condition. Below is what I tried but didn't worked. I want add two attributes (att1, att2) based on if condition

```
Parameters:  
Apptype:  
string  
Conditions:  
  CIsFinanacial:  
    !Equals [ !Ref Apptype, 'financial' ]

Projection:   
 NonKeyAttributes:   
    !If CIsFinanacial [!Join [","["att1", "att2"], !Ref AWS::Novalue]
```

The above if condition results as string (att1,att2) But I want them to provision as list of strings. For now as a work around I wrote as two conditions and two if conditions. But is there a way to provision them in one if condition.

SORRY for poor writing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following form should work (you also have spelling mistake in NoValue):

```
Projection:   
 NonKeyAttributes:   
    !If CIsFinanacial [["att1", "att2"], !Ref AWS::NoValue]
```

If not then you can be more explicit:

```
Projection:   
 NonKeyAttributes:   
    !If 
      - CIsFinanacial 
      - - "att1"
        - "att2"
      - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Comment: I got below error while using above. Value of property NonKeyAttributes must be of type List of String